# How to reply file (from AWS) in response from Node.js

Tags: node.js, networking, amazon-s3, filestream

I am using Node.js API to upload/download profile images. All the profile images are stored in the AWS s3 storage.

How to download the file from s3 to Node.js route and return the file to the client in response. I can't use file hosting because all the routes are protected with token and user may or may not have the access of certain profile images based on some logic.

Comment: You should stream the file from s3 to your response. Take a look at [downloadStream](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client#clientdownloadstreams3params) from the s3 SDK, it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Although s3 SDK works great but I have used simple stream from AWS to read and send the chuncks of data to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use getObject() to download the files form s3 bucket.
See the following example :-

```
var stream = require('stream');

const s3 = require('../config/s3.config.js');

exports.doDownload = (req, res) => {
 const s3Client = s3.s3Client;
 const params = s3.downloadParams;

 params.Key = req.params.filename;

 s3Client.getObject(params)
 .createReadStream()
 .on('error', function(err){
 res.status(500).json({error:"Error -> " + err});
 }).pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, Thanks for answer, I have another question similar to this. How to manage image file download from the client side, make sure to cache the image response and provide authentication to access the image file also ?